# How to install a package with yum on Amazon Opsworks

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef

I would like to install a single package with yum (or rpm) on my Amazon Opsworks instance when the instance starts. I have read about chef and recipes but all of the solutions seem very complex for an apparently simple and common task. I would like a simple example of how to install a package.

Answer (score 1):

In general what you're going to do us create a chef recipe which installs a single package, probably using [the `yum_package` resource](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_yum.html).

This can be a *very simple* one-line recipe, if you just want the latest version of the package:

```
yum_package "my_package"
```

Then, you will add a cookbook containing just this *setup recipe* to an [Opsworks custom layer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinglayers-custom.html). The custom layer doesn't need to do anything else if all you want is to install the package. But since the custom layer lets you do a lot more, you might want to read Amazon's documentation and some other sample cookbooks that it links to, to get a sense of what you can do.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So, in my cookbook git repo I create a sub-directory that is called server-setup and this is the name that I put into the setup field in my custom layer. Then under server-setup I create a directory called recipes, and in that directory I create a file called default.rb in which I put the line above (with my_package replaced). I get the error message "Cookbook Setup not found". What am I missing?